# Average Tries needed for conditionally looping probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I beg your pardon for the undescriptive title and it's lack of proper jargon. All of this has been quite a few years in the past for me.

Here is my problem displayed in image form:
[Paint Skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcssb.png)

---

As you can probably see, I want to know how to calculate the average tries needed to reach a "Done" state in a problem where you go back to the previous stage upon failure.

Stage 1: 1/14 odds at being **Done** in Stage 1, 13/14 odds to move to Stage 2.

Stage 2: 1/3 odds to move to Stage 3, 2/3 odds to have to move back to Stage 1.

Stage 3: 1/4 odds at being **Done**, 3/4 odds to move back to Stage 2.

I have legitimately no idea on how to approach this, as I can't think of a way to express the possibility of being stuck in loop between the stages and how many times you'd have to go through them for a success.

Add in the fact, that I need to know the average amount of times you are at each step because I want to know the associated cost, and I am completely lost.

I hope some kind soul here can enlighten me :)

---

Best wishes, kahntesy

Comment: As a suggestion:  for $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ let $E_i$ be the expected number of tries till Done assuming you start in state $i$.  Use the  given rules to get a system of linear equations in the $E_i$.  For instance, $E_1=\frac 1{14}\times 1 +\frac {13}{14}\times (E_2+1)=1+\frac {13}{14}\times E_2$

Comment: @lulu: I tried to follow your suggestion, but am getting rather weird results !

Comment: @trueblueanil  Looking at your posted solution....why do you think those results are weird?  They look sensible to me.    It's hard to get a cheap estimate but we can say something like "conditioned on ending from $A$ then you expect it to take at least $14$ tries (as it would take $14$ if you ignore the detours, and the detours make it worse).  Conditioned on ending from $C$ you expect more than $6$ as it would take $4$ if you start at $C$ and ignore detours and it takes at least $2$ tries to get to $C$.  So the answer must be $>6$."

Comment: @lulu: Thanks, I was  sure of the process, I guess at first glance the results appeared counter-intuitive !

Comment: @trueblueanil  I have posted an alternate solution just to confirm the state based method.  In this case, doing it directly isn't all that unpleasant (though the state based method is a lot simpler and, I think, a lot more powerful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labelling the nodes $1,2,3$ as $A, B, C$, we proceed step by step, eg

With $1$ step from $A$, we are either  done, or with Pr = $\frac{13}{14}$, we reach $B$

Framing equations for  movement step by step, for # of steps we get

$\displaylines{A = 1 +13B/14\\B = 1+C/3  + 2A/3\\C =1  +3B/4}$

Solving, we get $A = 167/11, B = 168/11, C = 137/11$

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I had a super busy week. The approach of this solution is something even I can grasp (I think) with my limited knowledge (and without a coffee), so I tremendously appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :}

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the argument based on states (as in the posted solution of @trueblueanil) is the best.  Just as a sanity check, here is an alternate solution:

Note that the probability of finishing on the first trial is $\frac 1{14}$.  If you survive the first trial (probability $\frac {13}{14}$) you are in stage $\#2$.  From this point, your probability of surviving the next two trials is $$\rho_s=\frac 23\times \frac {13}{14}+\frac 13\times \frac 34=
\frac {73}{84}$$

And, of course, the probability of being done after the next two trials is $$\rho_d=1-\rho_s=\frac {11}{84}$$

Clearly, having survived the first trial, you now have a Geometric Distribution with expectaton $\frac 1{\rho_d}=\frac {84}{11}$.  Thus the answer is $$\boxed {1 +\frac {13}{14}\times 2\times \frac {84}{11}=\frac {167}{11}}$$

Note that the factor of $2$ arises because each "trial" for stage $\#2$ is two ordinary trials.

To do it out completely:  note that the probability of being done in exactly $2n+1$ trials (for $n≥1$) is $$p_{2n+1}=\frac {13}{14}\times \rho_s^{n-1}\times \rho_d$$

It is now [easy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F14%29%2B%2813%2F14%29*%2811%2F84%29*sum%5B%282n%2B1%29*%2873%2F84%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) to compute the answer:

$$\boxed {E=\frac {1}{14}+\frac {13}{14}\times \rho_d\times \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n+1)\times \rho_s^{n-1}=\frac {167}{11}}$$

which, of course, matches the result given by the state based method.

Might be worth remarking that, technically, the argument via states is incomplete as it assumes existence.  The computational methods employed here demonstrate existence.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I had a super busy week.
I appreciate the incredibly indepth and well thought out reply and all the time that had to go into that! Sadly I can't upvote your Solution as I'm lacking some reputation, but I hope it makes you happy as well that you helped me learn something :)

Comment: @kahntesy  No worries about the points, and thanks for the kind words.  Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

First, note that there is no way you can do it in an even amount of tries. Moreover, there is 1/14 chance to finish in one try. If not, then you have 13/14 chance to go to stage 2, from which you have 1/3 odds to go back to stage 3, and 2/3 odds to go back to stage 1. As a result, for any $n\geq 1$, the probability that you'll finish in **exactly** $2n+1$ tries is given by
$$
p(2n+1)= \frac{13}{14}\left(\frac13\cdot\frac14+ \frac23\cdot\frac{1}{14}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\ k\end{pmatrix}\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac34\right)^{k}\left(\frac23\cdot \frac{13}{14}\right)^{n-1+k}\\
= \frac{13}{14}\cdot\frac{33}{252}\cdot\left( \frac{73}{88}\right)^n,
$$
because, it's a $\frac{13}{14}$ chance we go to step two, and then we know we'll go back to step two $n$ more times in total. So, first, choose in what step you'll be done. Going from step two to step three and then finishing the game has probability $\frac13\cdot\frac14$ while going from step two to step one and then finishing the game has probability $\frac23\cdot\frac{1}{14}$.

Moreover, for the rest $n-1$ times we'll visit step two, we choose $k$ of them to be for step three and $n-k+1$ to be on step one. Since going to step one from step two has a probability of $13/14$, and then from step two back to step one has probability $2/3$, and since these will happen $n-k+1$ times we multiply accordingly.

Since $p(1)= \frac14$, you may check that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n)= 1. 
$$

Now, the average is given by
$$
\sum_{n=1}np(n)= p(1)+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)p(2n+1)= \frac14+ \frac{429}{3528}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1)\left(\frac{73}{88}\right)^n\\
=\frac14+ \frac{858}{3528}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left( \frac{73}{88}\right)^n+ \frac{429}{3528}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{73}{88}\right)^n\\
=\frac14 + \frac{858}{3528}\frac{\frac{73}{88}}{\left( 1-\frac{73}{88}\right)^2}+ \frac{429}{3528}\left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{73}{88}}-1\right)\\
= \frac14+ \frac{858}{3528} \frac{73\cdot 88}{15^2}+ \frac{429}{3528}\frac{73}{15}\approx 3.1562,
$$
so you'll need a little more than three tries.

Comment: This answer is much too small.  Note that, conditioned on finishing from state $\#1$ you expect it to take more than $14$ trials (as it would take $14$ if you ignored the detours) and conditioned on finishing from state $\#3$ you expect more than $6$ (as it takes at least $2$ trials to get there and you expect more than $4$ from that point).

Comment: I don't think your calculations are accurate, even for the probability of finishing in $3$ trials), but you should easily see that finishing in $1$ or $3$ has less than a $.2$ chance....which means that you have a $.8$ chance of taking at least $5$ and already $.8\times 5=4$ which is greater than your result.

Comment: The fraction $\frac{73}{88}$ should be $\frac{73}{84}$ and I suspect there are some mistakes in the other fractions as well.